# Lubuntu keyboard problem

Tags: keyboard-layout, lubuntu

I have installed Lubuntu 11.10 for it's much lighter than Ubuntu itself with Unity, but I have serious problem. I need to put another keyboard layout- Bulgarian, but I simply can't do it. Tried a lot of things but can't figure out how to do it. Please help me for it's important. :) Thanks!

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. =)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the layouts to your .bashrc file. So, let's say you wanted `us` and `bg`, run `nano .bashrc`, scroll to the bottom, and add the following line:

```
setxkbmap -layout "us,bg" -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle"
```

`Ctrl+o` to save, `ctrl+x` to exit.

Then logout/login, and try `alt+shift`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to use two keyboard layouts (US and Bulgarian) systemwide and switch between them using both shift keys, edit the default keyboard file:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/default/keyboard
```

Modify the file so it includes the following:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,bg"
XKBVARIANT=","
XKBOPTIONS="grp:shifts_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
```

Save and exit. Now when you restart, you should be able to switch between the two layouts by hitting both shift keys at the same time. If you are using a different keyboard model or want to change layouts using a different key combination, you will have to modify the relevant line(s) in the example given above.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this command worked
You have to open a terminal (Ctrl+Shift+T) and type

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Then, when you are asked for the layout, choose Bulgarian. The latin layout will be added bu default